# Elixir HttpPoison not working to send multipart/form-data requests

Tags: http, erlang, elixir

I have a very simple request to make but it looks like [HttpPoison](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison) isn't able to resolve this.

The request has attachments, so i'm using `multipart/form-data` content type.

When I send just the file, the request works fine, but I need to add some other props to my request and that's where the issue comes.

My request:

```
HTTPoison.post(
  "path.com/api/anything",
  {:multipart, [
    {
      :file,
      "/path/file.xlsx",
      {"form-data", [name: "file", filename: "file.xlsx"]}, []
    },
    {"taskName", "#{task.name}"},
    {"taskLink", "#{task.link}"}
  ]},
)
```

I receive the file without problems but the `taskName` and `taskLink` never reach the server.

( *I tried with postman and had no problems* )

---

Some issues related to this:

https://elixirforum.com/t/httpoison-post-multipart-with-more-form-than-the-file/4222/4
https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/issues/237

Comment: I tried starting netcat with `nc -l 9999` and making this request to `http://localhost:9999` - and I can see the extra fields. But if I make the same request to `https://postman-echo.com/post`, it seems like it doesn't notice the fields. Perhaps it (and the server you're using) doesn't like that Hackney sends `content-length` and `content-type` headers?

Comment: The server is using node... I think you're right, when I make the request using axios (node) everything works fine. I'll investigate the difference between hackney and axios headers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We have a working example of the multipart list that we use to send zip files along with other attributes. Something equivalent to this might work for you.

```
[
  {"id", to_string(order_id)},
  {"file_size", to_string(file_size)},
  {"attachment", file, {"form-data", [name: "file", filename: filename]},
    [{"Content-Type", "application/zip"}]
  }
]
```

Comment: In our case, the `file` variable is an in-memory binary.

Comment: I think the poblem is that my server (using node) doesn't deal fine with some headers sent by HttpPoison (hackney). Can you tell me what you are using on your server? Thanks!

Comment: If you mean on the receiving end, I'm not sure.  We're posting to an API from another company.  We are using hackney 1.15.2 and httpoison 0.13.0, so it looks like we're quite a bit behind.